Exportación de datos python
Comunidad, tengan buenos días. Les quiero consultar sobre la exportación en txt.
Tengo una lista: [('aaa', 'aa', '1111/11/11'), ('bbb', 'bb', '2222/22/22')] (cuya longitud es variable de acuerdo al criterio de búsqueda).
Y me interesaría generar una salida del tipo:
col1    col2    col3
aaa     aa      1111/11/11
bbb     bb      2222/11/11

He intentado, con el siguiente código (ya que la salida debería ser un txt) precedido por un ciclo for:
with open("resultado4.txt", "a+") as f:
    print(resultado2, "\n",file=f)

como para, aunque sea, separar los ítems de la lista. Pero tampoco lo logré ya que sólo me guarda el primero o el último ítem de la lista.
Agradecería si pueden darme una indicación sobre cómo lograr la salida deseada a partir del ejemplo de lista dado.
Saludos.

Mostra tu codigo completo.. porque sin saber python, si decis que todo eso esta dentro de un ciclo, suena a que abris el archivo todo el tiempo...

Este código debería servirte, ya que escribe el resultado que quieres usando un bucle:
lista = [('aaa', 'aa', '1111/11/11'), ('bbb', 'bb', '2222/22/22'), ('ccc', 'cc', '3333/33/33'), ('ddd', 'dd', '4444/44/44')]
with open("resultado.txt", "a") as file:
  for item in lista:
    file.write(" ".join(item) + "\n")

resultado.txt:
aaa aa 1111/11/11
bbb bb 2222/22/22
ccc cc 3333/33/33
ddd dd 4444/44/44

Entre las comillas dobles del join debes poner el separador que necesites (espacio, coma, etc.).
Si necesitas los nombres de las columnas, puedes añadirlos al principio de la lista.

Bueno, he probado la solución de manera independiente y, efectivamente, funciona. Pero he tenido un problema. La lista original, consta de 7 ítems, cuando a la función le paso la lista original crea el txt pero vacío y el ide me arroja el siguiente mensaje de error: "TypeError: sequence item 8: expected str instance, int found" (error que no me aparece cuando la lista es ficticia como la del ejemplo). No entiendo por qué, arroja ese error en la lista real y no en la ficticia (la que usé como ejemplo) y no entiendo tampoco por qué llega a crear el txt pero sin contenido alguno.

Cierto, @aeportugal . Buen punto.

@Diego el error que te aparece es porque estás intentando escribir datos de tipo int. Asegúrate de convertir todos los datos a string cuando haces la escritura. Una buena forma sería con los f-string: f"{variable_int}". También puedes hacer la conversión mediante str(variable_int).

Rafael, entiendo lo que dices pero me choco de frente con dos problemas. El primero es que ningún dato es de tipo int. Son todos string. Hasta la fecha (el "11/11/1111") está pasada como string. Y luego, me hacía ruido que el error indicara el ítem 8 ("TypeError: sequence item 8: expected str instance, int found") siendo que la lista contiene sólo 7 ítems, así que metí todo dentro de un "while len(lista) > i" (definiendo i=0 y sumándole +1 en cada vuelta) y ahí ya no arroja el error. Pero sigue sin cargar los ítems al txt (lo sigue creando vacío). ¿¿??

@Diego si puedes compartir el código que estás usando para ver cómo creas y recibes los datos, a lo mejor podemos ayudarte mejor. Ahora mismo me encuentro un poco a ciegas.

@Diego, una pequeña aclaración,  sequence item 8: expected str instance, int found es un error lanzado por str.join, significa que una de las tuplas que conforman tu lista (los datos de una fila) tiene en el indice 8 (9ª columna de tu txt final) un entero (int). La lista puede tener 7 elementos/filas (tuplas), pero el error no se refiere a la lista principal, sino a una de las tuplas/sublistas que contiene que es lo que recibe join.

Por favor edita la pregunta y agrega todo el código relevante, incluido el ciclo que itera sobre la lista como GBianchi y Rafael te han pedido, el error se solventa como apunta Rafael, por ejemplo: f"{' '.join(str(col) for col in item)}\n", si te crea el archivo vacío, lo más probable es que la excepción comentada  se genere en la primera fila/tupla de la lista, por lo que no llega a escribirse nada en el archivo, Si no nos muestras todo el código relevante  solo podremos intentar adivinar cosas y se dificulta que tengas una respuesta concreta, certera y rápida.

Voy a hacer algo que no es recomendado aquí pero se lo merecen. Les agradezco enormemente el tiempo, la paciencia y la dedicación que me han tenido. Además, a @Rafael por ser quien dió la solución original, y a FJSevilla por ser quien me enseñó "sequence item 8: expected str instance, int found es un error lanzado por str.join, significa que una de las tuplas que conforman tu lista (los datos de una fila) tiene en el indice 8 (9ª columna de tu txt final) un entero (int)".  Pues resulta que ese entero se me había escapado y eso hacía el lío. Pero ya se ha resuelto todo con la ayuda de ambos.
